# Oracle APEX: Display Image

Tags: oracle, image, oracle-apex

i want to display these images in oracle apex:

Images are saved on local network share folder in following path:

```
\\SCANS\01\01-0001.GIF
\\SCANS\01\01-0002.GIF
\\SCANS\01\01-0003.GIF
...
\\SCANS\99\99-9999.GIF
```

Comment: So, are those files dynamic, as the `\\SCANS\` directory prefix indicates?  Generally, image files for APEX are stored in a database table column, or referenced via a URL, so for your case, you may need to have a web server expose those files to a URL that your APEX application references.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to upload those images to Oracle Apex using

Application --> Shared Components --> Static files --> Upload file

Then,once the images are in Apex, you can use #APP_IMAGES#nameoftheimage.gif to reference the image and use it in your application.

Regards

Comment: Hi, I have smilar requirement in apex where i need to store images in table. I have a table emp_data with emp_name and image which is blob column. So, if i store image in static files, can i just use #APP_IMAES#Allen.png in the column?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to SQL plus as SYS and create directory:

```
create directory my_img_dir as 'c:\my_images\';
```

Grant read privilege on directory to DAD user (ANONYMOUS):

```
grant read on directory my_img_dir to anonymous;
```

Grant read privilege on directory to your application parsing schema. Change "my_schema" to your own schema:

```
grant read on directory my_img_dir to my_schema;
```

Create new app and 2 blank pages. I assume first page (id 1) is where you show images. Second page (id 2) is just for call application process. Create application process point "On Load:Before Header"

```
DECLARE
l_lob     BFILE;
l_length  NUMBER;
BEGIN
l_lob :=  BFILENAME('MY_IMG_DIR', :REQUEST);
l_length := DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_lob);

htp.flush;
htp.init;

htp.p('Content-length: ' || l_length);

htp.p('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="&REQUEST."');

-- close the headers
owa_util.http_header_close;

-- download the BLOB
wpg_docload.download_file(l_lob);
--
END;
```

Make process conditional if page is 2. Create HTML region to page 1 and place to region source:

`<img src="f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&APP_SESSION.:my_picture.gif" alt="">`

Note: More info please go this link https://blog.jaris.fi/apex/f?p=BLOG:READ:::NO::ARTICLE:91800346957167

Answer (score 0):

1: Create Directory to save File and add privilege to write on Directory to You User

CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY STOCK_DIR2 AS 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\i\STOCK_IMAGE';

GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY STOCK_DIR2 TO STOCK;

2: Create column html expression in interactive grid Report

2: to get image dynamically

Note: this code copied from another blog. but fo preview image from directory i use this code

Answer (score 0):

If those images are accessible from the client's side from an URL you should be able to render them in you page without any intervention from the application server.

We have an "image bucket" from which I access most of the images required for the application and it is as simple as uploading static files to APEX.

if you want to render in an image tag you could

```
<img src="URL_TO_IMAGE"/>
```

and technically you could serve them as background images for tags using CSS

```
.selector{
     background-image:url(URL_TO_IMAGE);
}
```

Comment: hi, it's been a while. did it work?